# Let $F(x) = \int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)} e^{t^2 + xt} dt.$ Find $F'(0)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $F(x) = \int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)} e^{t^2 + xt} dt.$  Find $F'(0)$.

I am reviewing for the mGRE and I came across this problem. My first thought was to simple apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. Doing so, I get
$$-\cos(x)e^{\sin^2(x)+x\sin(x)}-\sin(x)e^{\cos^2(x)+x\cos(x)}\Big|_{x=0} = -1.$$

However, I believe the correct answer is $ {1 \over 2} (e-3)$.

Writing this out made me realize that the FTC might not apply as I have it due to the $x$ in the integrand. Either way, any tips or alternate methods would be appreciated.

Comment: You are applying the FTC incorrectly. You should look into differentiating integrals with respect to parameter. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under appropriate assumptions, with $F(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt$
we have
$F'(x) = f(x,b(x)) b'(x) - f(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x}dt$.

You are missing the last term, which evaluates to ${1 \over 2} (e-1)$ in your case.

Comment: I only changed dx to partial x at the end

Comment: @Squirtle: Thanks for catching that!